# How set colors for css selectors if css code is embeded?

Tags: notepad++

I have Notepad++ 6.4.5.

Is it possible to set different colors for css selectors if css code is EMBEDDED into php file, as if css code is in a separate file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately AFAIK you can't do such a distinction. It is because Notepad++ finds the proper coloring by the file extension or if you change the language for a single file. Therefore only one programming language's coloring is selected at the moment.